# iframe shows CORS on jQuery $.get()

Tags: javascript

i've two related websites, one shows the second in an iframe.
I was using both conrrectly until today that (I dk why) started to receive the follow message by console every time I load, using jQuery $.get(), a view:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at *PATH* from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

IT'S NOT COUSE THE LOCALHOST, i've upload the parent web and it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because the domains are different you cannot request data via an XMLHttpRequest get unless the other domain is white listed by the server in the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

If you want one domain to be able to allow cross domain request you need to add the domain in the header or a * to allow all domains to be able to get.

How to do this is completely dependent on the language you are using on the server.